# How can I change the text color and style of "module.exports" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the color or style of a custom text like `module.exports`. I don't want to change the color of properties or others. For example extensions like TODO Highlight, colorize the text `TODO:` in all documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting like so:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[<Name of Color Theme you want the change to apply to>]": { // TODO
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "support.type.object.module.js",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                "fontStyle": "bold" // TODO
            }
        }],
    },
}
```

If you want the change to apply to all colour themes instead of just one, then don't wrap the `textMateRules` field with the colour theme object wrapper.

To find the textmate scope that you want to change, use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` action to open [the Scope Inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector). Then click on the token you want to inspect, and a tooltip panel will appear showing what scopes the token matches.

See also [the docs for creating your own colour theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme).

Comment: how can I apply that to a custom text like `Tour.created` with d at the end and not for `Tour.create` which don't have d?

Comment: @Esmail you'd have to write a custom textmate grammar for matching it. But your question post is only about `module.exports`.